# How to convert Get-WinEvent's TimeCreated to yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss format?

Tags: date, powershell, datetime, time, powershell-2.0

In PowerShell 2.0 on Windows 7 I can format time/date format as the following:

```
Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss
```

and output is:

```
2016-06-07-01-04-16
```

But now I have the following command:

```
Get-WinEvent -max 1 | Select-Object TimeCreated, Id
```

and the output is:

```
7.6.2016 13:01:46   444
```

Note: 444 is the Id column, not important in our case.

How to format it with `yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss` to get:

`2016-06-07-13-01-46 444`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
Get-WinEvent -max 1 | Select-Object  @{name='TimeCreated'; expression={$_.TimeCreated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss")}}, Id
```

Comment: I think you have to use HH, so this will become: Get-WinEvent -max 1 | Select-Object  @{name='TimeCreated'; expression={$_.TimeCreated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss")}}, Id

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is:

```
Get-WinEvent -max 1 | Select-Object TimeCreated, Id,
    @{Name='SpecialDate';Expression={$_.TimeCreated.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss')}}
```

Which generates:

```
TimeCreated : 7/06/2016 13:21:17
Id          : 4648
SpecialDate : 2016-06-07-13-21-17
```

With `Get-Member` you can find all possibilities (Moethods, properties, ..) of a CmdLet:

```
Get-Date | Get-Member
```

With `Get-Help` you can find out how to use a CmdLet:

```
Get-Help Select-Object -Examples
```

Hopefully this helps you out.